# A design issue of a member function

Tags: c++

A Base class has a member function with this signature

```
virtual void method(A &a, B &b, C &c, D& d);
```

The user defines a derived class that overrides this method.

We discovered that the code of method was misleading as it had bad design:

- a is only an input and should not be modified
- b is only an output and MUST be set
- c is only an output , could be set or not
- d is an input and output in the same time so it should be read and could be set to a value inside the method.

The rest of the code will use the value given to b and will take benefit from the values of c and d if the are set.

Clearly this is bad design as for example a should be declared **const**.

Questions:

1. What about the objects b,c and d? is their a better way to declare this method in a way that takes into account the different behaviors?
2. How should we deprecate this method and replace it without impacting the code that is currently using this method?

Comment: I would make `B` a return value unless you need to reuse it's instances because it's very large and performance is critical.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but yes the performance is very critical in our application.

Comment: Not all code in an application is critical to performance. If the function is not called very often, then reusing objects has no benefits to performance. If that function really is critical to performance, you may want consider whether getting rid of virtual dispatch would be beneficial as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't provide any handy tools for this, like some other languages (e.g. in C#, `ref`, `out`, the `[Obsolete]` tag).

I have seen some people do this, though:

```
#define in
#define out
#define optional

// DEPRECATED
virtual void method(const A& a, out B& b, optional out C& c, in out D& d);
```

This of course makes no behavioral different and means nothing to the compiler, it's just prettiness for a human reader.

Aside from that, I think making the first parameter `const` is about the best you can do. Semantically there's not really anything better than just leaving them non-const references as you already have it.

As for marking it deprecated the best you can do is stick a comment on it, or maybe print out an "I'm deprecated, don't use me" warning message to the console or to a log file when the function is used.

Comment: Thanks. That is something I didnt think about. On the other side (for the non deprecated solution) do you also think that this method should be split into many methods. and do we need to force the user to define all the methods in the derived class while putting his actual code in only one of them

Comment: I did like @DanielDaranas's suggestion very much. You might only need one function that gets implemented by derived classes to do actual work. The output parameters (whichever ones are relevant to the derived class) could just be stored as member variables in the class, with getter functions in the base class to access the paremeters.

Answer (score 2):

I would go around the "false limitation" that it has to be a single method: clearly that's not true since the requirements seem to differ so wildly.

Split into multiple methods, with varying number of arguments, and suitable argument names of course.

Comment: +1 - In particular he could apply [Command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), so that first a **command** is executed (possibly with input parameters) and then results are asked for in individual **query** functions.

Comment: OK, let s say we split it. The user will need to define only one of those of course according to his own needs. should we force him to define the all of the methods while putting his code only in one of them?